# R2: Setting CORS policy with different methods per allowed-origins

Tags: cors, cloudflare, cloudflare-r2

I’m having trouble with setting the correct [CORS](https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/buckets/cors/) policy on my bucket on Cloudflare's R2.

What I want to achieve: the bucket may by accessed by via any webpage of any domain, but only with GET method is allowed (so POST/PUT/DELETE are blocked) and from my own domain all methods are allowed.

I’ve tried this but seems not valid:

```
[
  {
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
      "GET"
    ]
  }
  {
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "https://example.com/"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
      "GET",
      "PUT",
      "POST"
    ]
  }
]
```

Does anyone know how to set the CORS policy correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each CORS rule should be enclosed within curly braces **`{}`**, and there should be a comma **`,`** between each rule. Here's the corrected version of your CORS policy:

```
[
  {
    "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],
    "AllowedMethods": ["GET"]
  },
  {
    "AllowedOrigins": ["https://example.com"],
    "AllowedMethods": ["GET", "PUT", "POST"]
  }
]
```